# Java 8 - StackOverflow during build in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am in the process of migrating a web app to Java 8.  I can build the project outside of Eclipse with no issues, but I am seeing strange errors inside the ide.  First of all, a few of the projects (4 out of 25) used in the application are showing errors that do not make any sense.  For any object the implements the collection interface, I see an error saying "the type X is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <sometype>."  For example,

[image: error]

It is a java.util.collection.  I get the same error for decedent types as well.... eg.. map, tree, ArrayList... etc.

Also, when I do a project->clean, Eclipse throws a StackOverflow error when building these projects.  This is the trace from the log:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2015-12-09 15:50:54.309
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Build Project".
!STACK 0
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at     org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ParameterizedTypeBinding.substituteInferenceVariable(ParameterizedTypeBinding.java:856)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ParameterizedTypeBinding.substituteInferenceVariable(ParameterizedTypeBinding.java:856)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ParameterizedTypeBinding.substituteInferenceVariable(ParameterizedTypeBinding.java:856)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ParameterizedTypeBinding.substituteInferenceVariable(ParameterizedTypeBinding.java:856)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ParameterizedTypeBinding.substituteInferenceVariable(ParameterizedTypeBinding.java:856)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ParameterizedTypeBinding.substituteInferenceVariable(ParameterizedTypeBinding.java:856)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.ParameterizedTypeBinding.substituteInferenceVariable(ParameterizedTypeBinding.java:856)
```

.
.
.
repeating

I am seeing these errors in two different Eclipse environments.  STS 3.6.2 and Mars 4.5.1.  Anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Comment: It builds with the JDK, but not with Eclipse. Sounds a lot like an Eclipse bug.  [File a report](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_report_a_bug_in_Eclipse%3F)...

Comment: Perhaps the version of JVM used by Eclipse is different from the version you are using outside of Eclipse. Check to see how many JVM versions yo have installed and check to see that Eclipse is using the most current.

Comment: Even with the wrong build version you shouldn't get a `StackOverflowError` during compilation.

Comment: Same JVM.  I agree, it must be Eclipse related.

Answer (score 0):

On the problematic projects, it sounds like they are configured with an old JRE system library and our compliance level, not Java 8. Open the project properties, go to the Java Build path, and check what the JRE System Library is set to; it should be J2SE-1.8.

Comment: JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.8] -> for offending projects

Comment: Compliance level is also set to 1.8